# Yii routing + CPager

Tags: php, yii, routes

I have my own class for pagination

```
class MyPager extends CLinkPager
```

I have controller

```
class LetterController extends Controller
```

and route

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

Link to controller wiil be

```
http://DOMAIN/letter/1
```

but when i use pagination, links look like as

```
http://DOMAIN/letter?id=1&page=2
```

And i want

```
http://DOMAIN/letter/1?page=2
```

How can i do this?

I found, that if you run this code

```
var_dump(Yii::app()->createUrl('', array('id' => 1)));
var_dump($this->createUrl('', array('id' => 1)));
```

first var_dump show you letter/1

second var_dump show you letter?id=1

Comment: Do you have route's rule: `'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/index'`?

Comment: No, but i added it. No changes

Comment: If it works same with default CLinkPager, then pls remove it from question. Currently problem only with routes/URL creation as I see.

Comment: Btw, where have you added it? In top of routes list or in the bottom? Order matters there. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#createUrl-detail and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlRule#createUrl-detail for details

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse you create url from controller. It say's in function reference.

> Creates a relative URL for the specified action defined in this
>   controller.

You need to pass first argument.

> the URL route. This should be in the format of
>   'ControllerID/ActionID'. If the ControllerID is not present, the
>   current controller ID will be prefixed to the route. If the route is
>   empty, it is assumed to be the current action. If the controller
>   belongs to a module, the module ID will be prefixed to the route. (If
>   you do not want the module ID prefix, the route should start with a
>   slash '/'.)

And for CLinkPager you can change route.

```
$pager = new CLinkPager();
$pager->route = YOUR_ROUTE
```